# Android: how to run AsyncTask at regular interval in background service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

How do I run an `AsyncTask` at regular interval of 2 mins sleep for 10 times in the background service?

As VM stops my service at any time, my `AsyncTask` is also getting closed.

I have tried `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, `Timer`, `TimerTask` all gets stopped once `Service` gets stopped.

Is there a good option start with?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Nisha, Any information needed? I need to run a AsyncTask in the background at regular interval. I guess you know the service will be stopped VM at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Your service will never get stopped but you should show notification. Try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Foreground service displays notification and is never stopped.

Implement this code snippet in your service

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there any other way without showing Notification status bar?

Comment: No way without showing notification your service will get killed when android feels it need resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Handler? U can read more about this in this [link](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Thanks, quick question, does `Handler` get closed along with `Service`. `Service` will be killed for resource by VM. I need to run `AsyncTask` in the background even the App is not launched. So basically I opted `Service`. My implementation work, when `Service` doesn't get closed, but unfortunately the `Service` get closed by VM.